# 3-2-1 Contact (I think) episode involving an alien creature

Tags: story-identification, educational

I'll freely admit that I may be conflating memories here, but I'm 99% certain this was [3-2-1 Contact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-2-1_Contact), although I also watched [The Electric Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Electric_Company) and other educational programs at the time (somewhere in the late 1980s to early 1990s). It was a live-action segment (and, as was usual for the skit, was just one of several segments, although I'm pretty sure that it was more than one segment in the episode with one introducing the problem and another the solution). A group of kids (I don't remember anything about ethnicity, although given where I grew up in Kentucky, I suspect I would have noted it as odd if they weren't predominantly white) either discovered, or were shown, a furry alien that looked a bit like a tribble or a toupé. The creature reproduced rapidly, with the episode being about exponential growth. I had largely forgotten the episode until I read [Children's sci-fi story about a group of British(?) school children who find an alien animal](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/159220/childrens-sci-fi-story-about-a-group-of-british-school-children-who-find-an) and it made me remember.

I have a vague association in my head of an episode in the same period of time involving building a box out of Lego blocks and calculating how many Lego one would need for *N* boxes, but I could say if it was the same episode or just one in the same year, or even whether that really was the same series.

Comment: Hah... sadly, this is a case where Rubber Duck debugging did not help.

Comment: Cartoon or live-action? Was the whole episode focused on the aliens/exponents, or was it broken into segments?

Comment: 321 Contact seems to have been produced a bit earlier than the dates given (80-88): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3-2-1_Contact#Episodes

Comment: @NKCampbell: I can't pin down a date. I was born in 1980, and it was definitely before I went into middle school (1992). :-/

Comment: This sounds more like something from Square One TV than 3-2-1 Contact.  Contact did not have many fictional sketches, and it focused more on science than math.

Comment: Kind of [crites](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/forums/off-topic-5/respect-the-crites-1864465/)

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi: As I said, more like tribbles, or the [Hell Toupee](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0511100/).

Comment: What were these "tribbles" doing?